# How to add custom routes to resource route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

I have an `invoices_controller` which has resource routes. Like following:

```
resources :invoices do
  resources :items, only: [:create, :destroy, :update]
end
```

Now I want to add a send functionality to the invoice, How do I add a custom route as `invoices/:id/send` that dispatch the request to say `invoices#send_invoice` and how should I link to it in the views.

What is the conventional rails way to do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Add this in your routes:

```
resources :invoices do
  post :send, on: :member
end
```

Or

```
resources :invoices do
  member do
    post :send
  end
end
```

Then in your views:

```
<%= button_to "Send Invoice", send_invoice_path(@invoice) %>
```

Or

```
<%= link_to "Send Invoice", send_invoice_path(@invoice), method: :post %>
```

Of course, you are not tied to the POST method

Comment: Thanks! There was one problem though, when I use send method in controller, I get an argument error like this `ArgumentError in InvoicesController#show wrong number of arguments (2 for 0)` I guess rails uses the send keyword for some internals. Funny, changing all "send" to "bend" actually sent the emails, Now I guess, I have to figure out a new verb for sending invoices.

Comment: @SathishManohar ah ah! I didn't think about that! Yes, `send` is a method in Ruby http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-send. Maybe use `deliver` instead of `send` (my 2 cents)

Answer (score 4):

```
resources :invoices do
  resources :items, only: [:create, :destroy, :update]
  get 'send', on: :member
end

<%= link_to 'Send', send_invoice_path(@invoice) %>
```

It will go to the `send` action of your `invoices_controller`.

Answer (score 1):

```
match '/invoices/:id/send' => 'invoices#send_invoice', :as => :some_name
```

To add link

```
<%= button_to "Send Invoice", some_name_path(@invoice) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

In Rails >= 4, you can accomplish that with:

`match 'gallery_:id' => 'gallery#show', :via => [:get], :as => 'gallery_show'`

Answer (score 1):

resources :invoices do
  get 'send', on: :member
end